Что такое абстракция?
Знаю про абстракцию в ООП, и если я правильно понимаю, то это выделение и сосредоточение только на тех деталях объекта, которые позволят нам решить задачу. Но слышал ещё и про уровень абстракции и просто про абстракцию, которая не относится к ООП. Хотелось бы разъяснить данные моменты.

если совсем в общем смысле, то абстракции - это такой способ мышления, который позволяет объяснить компьютеру то, что от него требуется, и получить от компьютера результат, естественно тоже в максимально абстрактном виде

по сути - это и есть интеллект, только это такая ограниченная форма интеллекта, которая не предполагает самомодификацию [но не исключает оную]

абстракция - это выделение важного во взаимодействии (методы)

кто или что определяет некую важность? критерии некоей "важности" огласите пожалуйста

уровни абстракции - разделение общей абстракции на частные

"абстракция - это выделение важного во взаимодействии (методы)", простите, что? так абстракции - это набор взаимодействий? абстракциям это не нужно, для этого и есть методы, убираем методы [взаимодействия] - что остаётся?

Абстракция - это когда мы переходим от конкретных сущностей вроде клубники, бананов и яблок, где каждая ягода, каждый фрукт имеет свои особенности, к обобщённым классам Клубника, Банан, Яблоко с некими общими для любой ягоды или фрукта свойствами, например: цвет, вес, цена. Потом мы можем пойти ещё дальше к ещё более абстрактным классам Овощ, Фрукт, Ягода. Потом к ещё более абстрактному классу Еда. И т.д.


Знаю про абстракцию в ООП, и если я правильно понимаю, то это выделение и сосредоточение только на тех деталях объекта, которые позволят нам решить задачу.

Именно так. Абстракция - это когда мы переходим от конкретных сущностей вроде клубники, бананов и яблок, где каждая отдельная ягода, каждый отдельный фрукт имеет свои особенности, нам не интересные, к обобщённым классам Клубника, Банан, Яблоко с некими общими для любой ягоды или фрукта свойствами, например: цвет, вес, цена. Нас интересуют только эти свойства, а всё остальное мы отбрасываем. Получается тот самый "сферический конь в вакууме", имеющий довольно мало общего с реальным конём, но позволяющий решать некие физические задачи по моделированию поведения коней в природе.

Но слышал ещё и про уровень абстракции и просто про абстракцию, которая не относится к ООП. Хотелось бы разъяснить данные моменты.

Абстракция на самом деле относится к ООП. Это как бы нулевой пункт, предшествующий классической триаде ООП "инкапсуляция, наследование, полиморфизм". Без абстракции ООП невозможно. Иногда её называют вместе с триадой, иногда просто подразумевают, но без неё никуда.
Что касается уровней абстракции, то после описания классов Клубника, Банан, Яблоко мы можем пойти ещё дальше к ещё более абстрактным классам Овощ, Фрукт, Ягода. Потом к ещё более абстрактному классу Еда. Потом к классу Товар. На каждом из этих этапов мы скорее всего будем терять всё больше деталей предмета, который описываем, но зато получать возможность однотипно оперировать всё более разными сущностями.
Впрочем, можно абстрагироваться и не обобщая разные сущности, а моделируя одну и ту же сущность с разной степенью детализации. Уже упоминавшийся "сферический конь в вакууме" - это доведённый до абсурда пример абстрагирования, когда от коня осталась одна характеристика - радиус шара, которым мы его себе представляем, а окружающую коня среду во всей её разнообразности мы заменили на вакуум, то есть отсутствие какой-либо среды.

"Именно так. Абстракция - это когда мы переходим от конкретных сущностей вроде клубники, бананов и яблок, где каждая отдельная ягода, каждый отдельный фрукт имеет свои особенности", нет, не так, потому что не бывает отдельных "фруктов", бывает только один "фрукт" - это и есть абстракция, если вы пишете про отдельные "фрукты" - это несколько абстракций "фруктов" - и зачем это? в данном случае существует ровно одна абстракция фрукта, ровно одна абстракция клубники, ровно одна абстракция банана, ровно одна абстракция яблока

"с некими общими для любой ягоды или фрукта свойствами, например: цвет, вес, цена. Нас интересуют только эти свойства" - и это не так, потому что цвет, вес, цена - это такие же абстракции, только эти абстракции имеют свои деревья абстракций; абстракция "фрукта" - это родительская абстракция для абстракций яблока/банана/груши, и ровноодинаково [с точностью до абстракции] - у цены/цвета/веса - существуют свои родительские абстракции

"Что касается уровней абстракции, то после описания классов Клубника, Банан, Яблоко мы можем пойти ещё дальше к ещё более абстрактным классам Овощ, Фрукт, Ягода." и это не так, в данном случае клубника/банан/яблоко - это "плод", т.е. это одна абстракция "плода", при этом, перейти к родительской абстракции товара/еды - здесь невозможно, для этого используются интерфейсы, в данном случае у абстракции "плода" есть два интерфейса - это еда-able, и товар-able - это значит что абстракция "плода" имеет допустимую возможность [-able] быть едой и/или быть товаром

при этом, абстракции еды/товара - описываются в других деревьях абстракций, со своими родителями/потомками

выше изначально написано - " абстракции - это такой способ мышления, который позволяет объяснить компьютеру то, что от него требуется, и получить от компьютера результат, естественно тоже в максимально абстрактном виде" - это и есть ограниченная форма интеллекта, но понятное дело то, что каков ваш интеллект - таков будет интеллект и в компьютере - это перенос вашего интеллекта в компьютер, и ничем иным абстракции не являются, как абстракции организуете в деревья абстракций - такой интеллект и получите, и понятное дело что вменяемо перенести интеллект в компьютер способен далеко не каждый

@InterceptorTSK Вы такую простыню комментариев написали, что проще было бы её как отдельный ответ оформить ;)

ооп - мало имеет отношения к абстракциям, абстракции - это отражение реальности в кампутер, вот оно как есть в реальности - так и есть в кампутере - это абстракции; при этом, ооп способно [отчасти] ограниченно описать абстракции, и замутить экземпляры абстракций, однако же экземпляры абстракций - абстракциями не являются, это объекты; реализованная абстракция [экземпляр] перестаёт быть абстракцией, потому что теряет абстрактность как таковую, и тут наступает функциональщина, которая никому не интересна по определению
